# Перестает работать php-скрипт при подключении другого скрипта

Tags: php

Образовалась проблема с работой кэширующего скрипта при подключении второго скрипта, "достающего" часть контента из memcache.

По отдельности и один и второй работают прекрасно. А вместе что-то не хотят.

Код такой:

```
<?php /* Скрипт, проверяющий, есть ли в папке cache файл с текущим 
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) в названии. Если есть, то загружаем файл из 
папки cache. Если нет, то записываем вывод страницы в буфер */

$curr_url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (file_exists(__DIR__."/cache/

 $curr_url"))
{  
    readfile(__DIR__."/cache/$curr_url"); 
    exit();
} 
ob_start();

require_once './src/functions.php';
?>

//html текущей страницы:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>........................... </head>

 <body> //Всякий разный html, который мы и запишем в файл в папку cache

 ..................................................................

</body>
<?php  /**/ 
$buffer = ob_get_contents(); 

$fp = fopen(__DIR__."/cache/$curr_url", 'w'); 

fwrite($fp, $buffer);
ob_end_flush(); 

fclose($fp); 
?>
</html>
```

**В таком виде все прекрасно работает**. При первой загрузке страница записывается в cache и всем последующим посетителям она отдается оттуда без обращения к файлам хостинга.

**Но, стоит мне часть своего html внутри body подключить скриптом из memcache, как скрипт буферизации/записи перестает работать.**
Т.е. если внутри body вместо части кода я пишу:

```
<?php 
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/memcache.php';
?>
```

**то скрипт буферизации/записи не выполняется.**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина.
Может, какая-то совсем глупая ошибка? Сильно не пинайте, я ж чайник в php.
Спасибо!

P.S. Журнал ошибок на хостинге сообщает о такой ошибке: 
Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Memcached::close() in /var/www/basefla1/data/www/baseflat.ru/src/memcache.php on line 35\n

НО У МЕНЯ В ЭТОМ ФАЙЛЕ НЕТ ТАКОЙ КОМАНДЫ. Там написано:
    $memcache_obj->close();
Да и при выполнении этого скрипта отдельно от второго никакой ошибки не происходит.

Код файла, подключаемого в html:

```
<?php

$stat = file_get_contents(__DIR__. '/constant.html');
$our_var = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);


$memcache_obj = new Memcached();
$memcache_obj->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

$var_key = @$memcache_obj->get($our_var);
    if(!empty($var_key))
        {
         echo $var_key;
        }
    else    {
        $memcache_obj->set($our_var, $stat, false, 2629743);            

            echo $memcache_obj->get($our_var);
        }
    $memcache_obj->close();

?>
```

Comment: Каждый из скриптов работает по отдельности. Но не работают вместе. А не профессионализм я не претендую

Comment: Эдуард, определила просто: в папке cache, в которую должен сохраняться файл с именем __DIR__."/cache/$curr_url"  перестал появляться такой файл. Без подключения кода из memcache файл сохраняется. А при подключении - нет.

Comment: Не надо писать в заголовке "решено". Если вопрос решен - примите ответ решающий проблему.

Comment: Я могу это сделать только через 2 дня

Answer (score 1):

Запуталась в именах переменных и названиях сервера / расширения.

Мне подсказали вот что:
У **memchached** нет метода close, нужно использовать quit.

close - у **memcache**.

Заменила на

> $memcache_obj->quit();

и все заработало как нужно.

Comment: Тогда вам минусов тележку за то что вводили людей в заблуждение тем, что писали - по отдельности файлы работают.

Comment: Они работали :(